# Google Map - Convert v2 to v3 -drag icon and retrieve lat/long

Tags: google-maps

I have an application that I wrote years ago in Google Map v2 that displayed a map from a given initial lat/long  and placed an icon on the map.  This webpage was a form with a text box for the lat and long.  The page allowed the user to drag the icon to actual location of where a wildfire was located.  The new lat/long was placed into the text box and the user could submit the form.   I have not found a suitable replacement in v3 for this process.  And now I get an error message that a new API key is required from Google Maps.  But I also know that in May that v2 may no longer work.  So I would like to update this app to v3.    Any ideas of where I can find this?  Here is an example of the old page  http://nfsdata.unl.edu/wildfire/testmap.asp  The page is writen in ASP.  And we do not have access to PHP on this server. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any relevant code you could share?

Answer (score 1):

That is a very straightforward application.

Your v2 code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function load() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    var center = new GLatLng(41.33,-96.95);
    map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());      
    map.setCenter(center, 13);
    var marker = new GMarker(center, {draggable: false});
    map.addOverlay(marker);
    GEvent.addListener(map, "click", function(overlay, point) { 
                    if (overlay) { 
                            map.removeOverlay(overlay); 
                    } else { 
                            map.clearOverlays() 
                            map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point)); 
                            document.getElementById("loclats").value = point.lat(); 
                            document.getElementById("loclongs").value = point.lng(); 

                    } 
    }); 


  }
}

//]]>
</script>
```

Simple translation to v3 (not tested):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function load() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(41.33,-96.95);
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),{
         center:center,
         zoom: 13
    });
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: map,
         position:center
    });
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
         marker.setMap(null);
    }); 
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(evt) { 
         var point = evt.latLng;
         marker.setPosition(point);
         document.getElementById("loclats").value = point.lat(); 
         document.getElementById("loclongs").value = point.lng(); 
    }); 


  }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_simpleMap_click4coords.html)